# Pass Javascript array to the back end with post

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I am trying to pass a javascript array to the back end. But apparently, I am not expecting the right type in the back end. What type should I expect? I added the delete method as well. Do I need to iterate in this array to be able to delete records?

```
[{"questionId":135,"answer":"A6.1"},{"questionId":135,"answer":"A6.2"}]

function deleteAnswers(arrayToDelete) {
    $http.post(baseUrl + "Admin/deleteAnswers", {data: arrayToDelete})
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {})
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult deleteAnswers(string  data) {
    Console.Write(data);
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    return Content("Sucess");
}


public void deleteAnswers(dynamic answersToDelete) {
    try {
        using (TestEntities testEntity = new TestEntities()) {
            foreach (var item in answersToDelete) {
                Console.Write(item.);
                //remove from 
            }
            testEntity.SaveChanges();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stringify the data and send it. How are you forming the array?

Comment: That works. I added the delete method as well. Do I need to iterate to delete. And how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an object with a property `data` with an array value, so your signature should look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult deleteAnswers(MyObject data)
{
    Console.Write(data);
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    return Content("Sucess");
}

public class MyObject {
    public List<Answer> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Answer {
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to modify the data that I am sending with the http post

Comment: @LMe send it as a json

Comment: Which one is the better approach stringify and send it or the object approach?